# How to get all items between two created_on dates for a Podio app

Tags: ruby, podio

I have an app that contains items with corrupted data that I would like to update. It's a few hundred items that fall between specific dates. How can I retrieve all items created between `"2020-08-22 20:43:13"` and `"2020-08-27 12:35:53"` using the ruby client?

I've tried the following:

```rb
Podio::Item.find_all(24993043, filters: {created_on: '2020-08-20'}, sort_by: 'created_on')
#=> Podio::BadRequestError: Invalid value "filters[created_on]" (string): Invalid filtering key

Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(24995043, filters: {created_on: "2020-08-20-2020-08-26"})
#=> Podio::BadRequestError: Invalid value "filters" (string): Invalid filtering key

Podio::Item.find_by_filter_values(24995043, created_on: "2020-08-20")
#=> Invalid value "2020-08-20" (string): must be object
```

Comment: Did you tried to use `Time.parse("2020-08-20")`?

Comment: I did not. I read this about `/tasks` in the API reference and assumed formatting the date will be the same across all endpoints: The from and to date the task should be completed between. Format: "YYYY-MM-DD-YYYY-MM-DD". Example for all tasks completed in Jun 2017: "2017-06-01-2017-06-30" 

I did just give your suggestion a try but got the same invalid value error.